# "No match for operator" when including QtSql library in QT

Tags: c++, qt

Upon writing include for the QtSql library into the code, any attempt at compilation returns "no match for operator". Deleting/commenting out the line with "include" gets rid of the errors.

The exact errors that occur are:

```
no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::thread::native_handle_type{aka ptw32_handle_t}' and 'std::thread::native_handle_type{aka ptw32_handle_t}')
no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'std::thread::native_handle_type{aka ptw32_handle_t}' and 'std::thread::native_handle_type{aka ptw32_handle_t}')
```

The files in my project:

Upload.pro

```
QT += core
QT -= gui
QT += sql

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = Upload
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

unix|win32: LIBS += -L'C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/lib/' -llibpq

INCLUDEPATH += 'C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/include'
DEPENDPATH += 'C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/include'
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QtSql>
#include <QSqlQuery>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    return 0;
}
```

I am using QT 5.12.0 with QT Creator 4.8.0 (MinGW 7.3.0 64 bit is set as compiler).

The program was installed with an offline installer, so it's not custom-built, which is why I'm hesitant to consider it a bug in program itself. Searching for similar issues also didn't give me any results.

I have previously solved similar sql-related programming problems using an earlier version of QT on a 32-bit computer, so I'm almost sure the code is fine as well.

Is this an issue with compiler settings? Or is that some complication in a newer version of QT?

**EDIT:** A fragment of the error message

[image]

**EDIT 2:** A fragment of error log (full error log is 226k+ characters long, which exceeds post limit)

```
14:13:47: Running steps for project Upload...
14:13:47: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
14:13:47: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\Tools\mingw730_64\bin\mingw32-make.exe" -j8
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'E:/User/databasePrograms/build-Upload-Desktop_Qt_5_12_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug'
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DMINGW_HAS_SECURE_API=1 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I..\Upload -I. -I"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\include" -IC:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include -IC:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include\QtSql -IC:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -IC:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\mkspecs\win32-g++  -o debug\main.o ..\Upload\main.cpp
In file included from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/future:39:0,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/qthread.h:50,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/QtCore:229,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtSql/QtSqlDepends:3,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include\QtSql/QtSql:3,
                 from ..\Upload\main.cpp:6:
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/thread: In function 'bool std::operator==(std::thread::id, std::thread::id)':
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/thread:276:26: error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::thread::native_handle_type {aka ptw32_handle_t}' and 'std::thread::native_handle_type {aka ptw32_handle_t}')
     return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/thread:270:3: note: candidate: bool std::operator==(std::thread::id, std::thread::id)
   operator==(thread::id __x, thread::id __y) noexcept
   ^~~~~~~~
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/thread:270:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::thread::native_handle_type {aka ptw32_handle_t}' to 'std::thread::id'
In file included from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/memory:81:0,
                 from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/thread:39,
                 from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/future:39,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/qthread.h:50,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/QtCore:229,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtSql/QtSqlDepends:3,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include\QtSql/QtSql:3,
                 from ..\Upload\main.cpp:6:
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/shared_ptr.h:378:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp> bool std::operator==(std::nullptr_t, const std::shared_ptr<_Tp>&)
     operator==(nullptr_t, const shared_ptr<_Tp>& __a) noexcept
     ^~~~~~~~
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/shared_ptr.h:378:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/future:39:0,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/qthread.h:50,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/QtCore:229,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtSql/QtSqlDepends:3,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include\QtSql/QtSql:3,
                 from ..\Upload\main.cpp:6:
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/thread:276:33: note:   'std::thread::native_handle_type {aka ptw32_handle_t}' is not derived from 'const std::shared_ptr<_Tp>'
     return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
                                 ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/memory:81:0,
                 from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/thread:39,
                 from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/future:39,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/qthread.h:50,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/QtCore:229,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtSql/QtSqlDepends:3,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include\QtSql/QtSql:3,
                 from ..\Upload\main.cpp:6:
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/shared_ptr.h:373:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp> bool std::operator==(const std::shared_ptr<_Tp>&, std::nullptr_t)
     operator==(const shared_ptr<_Tp>& __a, nullptr_t) noexcept
     ^~~~~~~~
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/shared_ptr.h:373:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/future:39:0,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/qthread.h:50,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/QtCore:229,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtSql/QtSqlDepends:3,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include\QtSql/QtSql:3,
                 from ..\Upload\main.cpp:6:
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/thread:276:33: note:   'std::thread::native_handle_type {aka ptw32_handle_t}' is not derived from 'const std::shared_ptr<_Tp>'
     return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
                                 ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/memory:81:0,
                 from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/thread:39,
                 from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/future:39,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/qthread.h:50,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/QtCore:229,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtSql/QtSqlDepends:3,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include\QtSql/QtSql:3,
                 from ..\Upload\main.cpp:6:
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/shared_ptr.h:368:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp, class _Up> bool std::operator==(const std::shared_ptr<_Tp>&, const std::shared_ptr<_Up>&)
     operator==(const shared_ptr<_Tp>& __a, const shared_ptr<_Up>& __b) noexcept
     ^~~~~~~~
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/shared_ptr.h:368:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/future:39:0,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/qthread.h:50,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/QtCore:229,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtSql/QtSqlDepends:3,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include\QtSql/QtSql:3,
                 from ..\Upload\main.cpp:6:
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/thread:276:33: note:   'std::thread::native_handle_type {aka ptw32_handle_t}' is not derived from 'const std::shared_ptr<_Tp>'
     return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
                                 ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/shared_ptr.h:52:0,
                 from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/memory:81,
                 from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/thread:39,
                 from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/future:39,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/qthread.h:50,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/QtCore:229,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtSql/QtSqlDepends:3,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include\QtSql/QtSql:3,
                 from ..\Upload\main.cpp:6:
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1420:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp, __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp> bool std::operator==(std::nullptr_t, const std::__shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>&)
     operator==(nullptr_t, const __shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>& __a) noexcept
     ^~~~~~~~
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1420:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/future:39:0,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/qthread.h:50,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/QtCore:229,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtSql/QtSqlDepends:3,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include\QtSql/QtSql:3,
                 from ..\Upload\main.cpp:6:
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/thread:276:33: note:   'std::thread::native_handle_type {aka ptw32_handle_t}' is not derived from 'const std::__shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>'
     return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
                                 ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/shared_ptr.h:52:0,
                 from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/memory:81,
                 from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/thread:39,
                 from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/future:39,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/qthread.h:50,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/QtCore:229,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtSql/QtSqlDepends:3,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include\QtSql/QtSql:3,
                 from ..\Upload\main.cpp:6:
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1415:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp, __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp> bool std::operator==(const std::__shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>&, std::nullptr_t)
     operator==(const __shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>& __a, nullptr_t) noexcept
     ^~~~~~~~
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1415:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/future:39:0,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/qthread.h:50,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/QtCore:229,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtSql/QtSqlDepends:3,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include\QtSql/QtSql:3,
                 from ..\Upload\main.cpp:6:
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/thread:276:33: note:   'std::thread::native_handle_type {aka ptw32_handle_t}' is not derived from 'const std::__shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>'
     return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
                                 ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/shared_ptr.h:52:0,
                 from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/memory:81,
                 from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/thread:39,
                 from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/future:39,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/qthread.h:50,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/QtCore:229,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtSql/QtSqlDepends:3,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include\QtSql/QtSql:3,
                 from ..\Upload\main.cpp:6:
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1409:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp1, class _Tp2, __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp> bool std::operator==(const std::__shared_ptr<_Tp1, _Lp>&, const std::__shared_ptr<_Tp2, _Lp>&)
     operator==(const __shared_ptr<_Tp1, _Lp>& __a,
     ^~~~~~~~
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1409:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/future:39:0,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/qthread.h:50,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/QtCore:229,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtSql/QtSqlDepends:3,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include\QtSql/QtSql:3,
                 from ..\Upload\main.cpp:6:
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/thread:276:33: note:   'std::thread::native_handle_type {aka ptw32_handle_t}' is not derived from 'const std::__shared_ptr<_Tp1, _Lp>'
     return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
                                 ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/memory:80:0,
                 from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/thread:39,
                 from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/future:39,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/qthread.h:50,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/QtCore:229,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtSql/QtSqlDepends:3,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include\QtSql/QtSql:3,
                 from ..\Upload\main.cpp:6:
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/unique_ptr.h:694:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp, class _Dp> bool std::operator==(std::nullptr_t, const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&)
     operator==(nullptr_t, const unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& __x) noexcept
     ^~~~~~~~
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/unique_ptr.h:694:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/future:39:0,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/qthread.h:50,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/QtCore:229,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtSql/QtSqlDepends:3,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include\QtSql/QtSql:3,
                 from ..\Upload\main.cpp:6:
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/thread:276:33: note:   'std::thread::native_handle_type {aka ptw32_handle_t}' is not derived from 'const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>'
     return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
                                 ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/memory:80:0,
                 from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/thread:39,
                 from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/future:39,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/qthread.h:50,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/QtCore:229,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtSql/QtSqlDepends:3,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include\QtSql/QtSql:3,
                 from ..\Upload\main.cpp:6:
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/unique_ptr.h:689:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp, class _Dp> bool std::operator==(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&, std::nullptr_t)
     operator==(const unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& __x, nullptr_t) noexcept
     ^~~~~~~~
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/unique_ptr.h:689:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/future:39:0,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/qthread.h:50,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/QtCore:229,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtSql/QtSqlDepends:3,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include\QtSql/QtSql:3,
                 from ..\Upload\main.cpp:6:
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/thread:276:33: note:   'std::thread::native_handle_type {aka ptw32_handle_t}' is not derived from 'const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>'
     return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
                                 ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/memory:80:0,
                 from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/thread:39,
                 from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/future:39,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/qthread.h:50,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/QtCore:229,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtSql/QtSqlDepends:3,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include\QtSql/QtSql:3,
                 from ..\Upload\main.cpp:6:
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/unique_ptr.h:683:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp, class _Dp, class _Up, class _Ep> bool std::operator==(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&, const std::unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>&)
     operator==(const unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& __x,
     ^~~~~~~~
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/unique_ptr.h:683:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/future:39:0,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/qthread.h:50,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/QtCore:229,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtSql/QtSqlDepends:3,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include\QtSql/QtSql:3,
                 from ..\Upload\main.cpp:6:
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/thread:276:33: note:   'std::thread::native_handle_type {aka ptw32_handle_t}' is not derived from 'const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>'
     return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
                                 ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/random:51:0,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/qrandom.h:45,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/QtCore:165,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtSql/QtSqlDepends:3,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include\QtSql/QtSql:3,
                 from ..\Upload\main.cpp:6:
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/random.tcc:1878:5: note: candidate: template<class _RealType1> bool std::operator==(const std::normal_distribution<_RealType>&, const std::normal_distribution<_RealType>&)
     operator==(const std::normal_distribution<_RealType>& __d1,
     ^~~~~~~~
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/random.tcc:1878:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/future:39:0,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/qthread.h:50,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/QtCore:229,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtSql/QtSqlDepends:3,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include\QtSql/QtSql:3,
                 from ..\Upload\main.cpp:6:
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/thread:276:33: note:   'std::thread::native_handle_type {aka ptw32_handle_t}' is not derived from 'const std::normal_distribution<_RealType>'
     return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
                                 ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/functional:58:0,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/qmap.h:54,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include\QtCore/qdebug.h:47,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include\QtCore/QDebug:1,
                 from ..\Upload\main.cpp:4:
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/std_function.h:770:5: note: candidate: template<class _Res, class ... _Args> bool std::operator==(std::nullptr_t, const std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>&)
     operator==(nullptr_t, const function<_Res(_Args...)>& __f) noexcept
     ^~~~~~~~
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/std_function.h:770:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/future:39:0,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/qthread.h:50,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/QtCore:229,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include/QtSql/QtSqlDepends:3,
                 from C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include\QtSql/QtSql:3,
                 from ..\Upload\main.cpp:6:
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.0/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/thread:276:33: note:   'std::thread::native_handle_type {aka ptw32_handle_t}' is not derived from 'const std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>'
     return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
                                 ^~~~~~~~~

mingw32-make[1]: *** [Makefile.Debug:380: debug/main.o] Error 1
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:36: debug] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'E:/User/databasePrograms/build-Upload-Desktop_Qt_5_12_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug'
14:13:52: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\Tools\mingw730_64\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project Upload (kit: Desktop Qt 5.12.0 MinGW 64-bit)
When executing step "Make"
14:13:52: Elapsed time: 00:05.
```

Comment: Don't include compiler messages as images. Write them as text *in* the question.

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem some years ago. An easy workaround was to copy the header files, delete everything that I didn't need then include the modified header on the project.

I didn't need the part with the issue and the name resolution worked as well.

Comment: Modifying library headers to work around a build issue sounds like a hack to me. Obviously that's not how the library was intended to be used. If you had to do that, then you were doing something wrong - don't advocate that as a solution.

Comment: He only needs the declaration of the function, all the rest is already built on the .so

Linking to a modified header in this way is harmless cause it will only remove non-used parts, most of them necessary only to build the .so itself.

The problem is a bug in Qt MinGW integration, obviously that's not how the library was intended to be used, mainly because it was intended to compile properly. Sadly it is not possible, so we can only sit and wait for Qt team to look into this super-specific problem, or play a safe workaround.